# Error with reinstall service pack 1 for Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I wanted to install VS 2010 Ultimate. Already i have VS Express C# and Web Developer. When I download ultimate version, during instalation i had an error with Service pack 1 for VS. I tried to uninstall SP1, but i have this errors:

```
Number of applicable items: 2
WM_ACTIVATEAPP: Focus stealer's windows WAS visible, NOT taking back focus
Patch () Uninstall succeeded on product (Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express - ENU). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall succeeded on product (Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express - ENU). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall succeeded on product (Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall failed on product (Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites - English). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express Prerequisites x64 - ENU). Msi Log: 
Exe (d:\eda4099f7bd96409fc6d81113d28\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
Patch () Uninstall failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall failed on product (Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites - English). Msi Log: 
Patch () Uninstall failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express Prerequisites x64 - ENU). Msi Log: 
MSI (C:\Users\Wazzaap\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20121009_103241668-MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Błąd krytyczny podczas instalacji. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:19:07).
```

How to repair it? I want to have Ultimate version and webdeveloper also. But this Service Pack seems to be broken.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a fixit tool created by Microsoft.

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9666880

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the installed products regarding VS and developer tools?

Comment: fixit tool with Windows Update was the best solution. Thanks!